# JMeter- how do I find out max number of users without issues?

Tags: jmeter

For 300 users, towards the end of the test, I can see that a few requests (about 10 or so) fail and the Response Data is 'request timeout' or connection failed errors.  How do I find out in Jmeter if this is due to the max performance reached or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'request timedout' errors you see when you gradually increase the no of threads give you an idea of max limit of the server.

`Thransaction Throughput vs Threads` is a nice metric to understand what is going on - It can give metric as shown here

[image]

> In the heavy load zone or Section B, as the concurrent client load increases, throughput remains relatively constant. However, the response time increases proportionally to the user load. That is, if the user load is doubled in the heavy load zone, the response time doubles. At some point, represented by Section C, the buckle zone, one of the system components becomes exhausted. At this point, throughput starts to degrade. For example, the system might enter the buckle zone when the network connections at the web server exhaust the limits of the network adapter or if the requests exceed operating system limits for file handles.

---

You should also monitor the server side metrics like CPU/Memory utilization etc. To find out, You need an agent running on the server to get the server metrics. You also should check the application log.
This example might give you an idea.

http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-server-performance-metrics-collector/